# Target repeating class within one div within one parent

Tags: jquery

I have the class `button_cta` in multiple places and would like to target it inside a `div` called `mid-parent` which is inside a `div` called `big-parent` and add the class `not_united` on it.

Using the code below the class is added but inside a sibling div to `mid-parent` inside there is a `button_cta` as well and it adds the class there too.

How do I target it only inside the `mid-parent` which is inside the `big-parent`?

I can't just target the `mid-parent` as that class is also used on other places and I need it to be targeted only when it's inside `big-parent`

```
$('.mid-parent').closest('.big-parent').find('.button_cta').addClass('not_united');
```

Comment: Can you please copy+paste the HTML in to the question. You'll get much more accurate answers more quickly if you show code instead of describe it

Comment: Work downwards?  `$("div.big-parent div.mid-parent .button_cta").addClass("not_united");` or `$("div.big-parent > div.mid-parent > .button_cta").addClass("not_united");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the description, the simplest approach would be suitable here. Either my English is not so good. It would be cool if html markup was provided.

```
$('.big-parent .mid-parent .button_cta').addClass('not_united');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked making your target more specific. I will recommend usng something along the line of:

```
$('div.mid-parent').closest('div.big-parent').find('.button_cta').addClass('not_united');
```

If 'button_cta' is a button you can even state that as well:

```
$('.mid-parent').closest('.big-parent').find('button.button_cta').addClass('not_united');
```

This way you make your target more specific

You can also use the parent and siblings methods in jQuery. For example:

```
$(this).parent('.parent').siblings('.siblings').children('.children').addClass("myClass");
```

jQuery allows you assign parent and siblings to classes, creating a hierarchical order.

Source: [Seek more clarification from Code Grepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/jquery+find+child+of+parent+sibling)